# How to control the visibility to Cesium/CZML DataSources

Tags: javascript, angular, cesiumjs, czml

I have a CZML datasource declared:

```
public geometryDataPromise: Cesium.CzmlDataSource;
```

I am loading it with an endpoint above when a component is loaded:

```
    if(!this.store.geometryDataPromise) {
        this.store.geometryDataPromise = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(environment.apiBaseURL + `/protectedareas/geometry/all`);
    }
```

all the rendered objects are displayed to terrain but trying to follow the instructions by doing:

```
this.store.geometryDataPromise.show = false;
```

the objects are not being hidden

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load` does not return a `Cesium.CzmlDataSource`.  It returns a `Promise` to asynchronously go get a `CzmlDataSource`, and that's not the same thing at all.  Your code is trying to show or hide the promise, that's not a thing that gets displayed.

```
var dataSourcePromise = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load( ... );
var dataSource = null;

dataSourcePromise.then(function(d) { dataSource = d; });
```

Note that after the above code runs, dataSource will be `null` for some time while the browser waits for the server's response to finish downloading.  Once the callback function fires, the dataSource is ready.

```
function onClick() {
    if (dataSource !== null) {
        dataSource.show = !dataSource.show;
    }
}
```

You can wire up a click handler for a toggle button like this.  But the toggle won't do anything until after the dataSource is downloaded and ready.

Answer (score 0):

First I have to take the result of the  `Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load` promise

```
Cesium.when(Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(environment.apiBaseURL + `/protectedareas/geometry/all`), result => {
        this.sources = result;
        this.viewer.dataSources.add(this.sources);

});
```

and then just change it's fiend `show` when the visibility changed

`this.store.sourceVisibility.subscribe(visibility=>this.sources.show=visibility);`